# post page through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hi i want to submit the page through following code but i can't get post data on ajax.php 
please tell me where i am wrong

```
new Ajax(wgScriptPath +'/' + 'ajax.php', {
              method: 'post',
              data:{items:item},
              onComplete: function(res)
{
              ////Code
}
```

Comment: more info, which library are you using?

Comment: The code as is is also flawed, there's a missing closing parenthesis (`)`).

Comment: is this protype js framework?

Answer (score 2):

to keep it simple and fast you can use open source jquery.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

check links below
- http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

example

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "test.php",
            data : "ffs=somedata&ffs2=somedata2",
            success : function() {
                alert("something");
            } 
        });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox" id = "checkbox">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention the framework you are using, assuming you are using prototype, try below code

```
new Ajax(wgScriptPath +'/' + 'ajax.php', {
              method: 'post',
              parameters:{items:item},
              onComplete: function(res)
{
              ////Code
}
});
```

Comment: i am usig mootooo.js for this